# How to calculate mass from compound lever?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, mass

A class 1 lever and a class 2 lever are connected in series, on the resistance end of the class one lever is a 500g weight. On the 2nd class lever sits a weight of an unknown mass. From the end of the 1st class lever to the center of the known mass is 46cm, from center of the known mass to fulcrum is 4cm. On the left side of the fulcrum the lever arm is 50cm. The 2nd class lever sits on the force end of the 1st class lever and their arms overlap 2cm. From the end of the 2nd class lever to the center of the known mass is 47cm. From the center of the unknown mass to the 2nd class fulcrum is 45cm. From Fulcrum to the right is 8cm. Calculate the unknown mass.  (The answer should be 200g)

Picture representation: 
[image: Picture]

I can't seem to get this to work, I've tried using the $\frac{m_k}{d_k} = \frac{m_?}{d_?}$ with this but to no avail. I've discussed with some others about using the torque of the levers but I can't get that to work either. (Where $t = FL$ and $t_1-t_2 =0=t_3-t_4$ and I can't get that to work either.) Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Image does not work for me

Comment: I've updated the link so it should now display, sorry about that.

Comment: Are these numbers from a physics problem or from a physical device? (Science Olympiad, perhaps!?) If it's the latter, then you'll need to also account for the mass of the lever arms.

Comment: Still no picture.

Comment: Re-uploaded to a different image hoster, let me know now. This is a physical device, the rulers are 110.6g each, but even when I include that in my calculations it doesn't seem to work right.